# How to get caret index of an editable div with respect to its html content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a html editor which helps user to suggest words based on what they type, like twitter editor.
The editor is a div whose contenteditable property set to true.
Everything was fine until word replacement.

Consider an example

```
<div id="editableDiv" contenteditable="true">
    the @tw
</div>
```

Please see the [screenshot](http://snag.gy/fDyR9.jpg)
When user types `@`, the suggestion list pops up and at the same time, I'll store this recently typed `@` index for later use by calling below function.

```
getCaretPosition : function(){
       var element = document.getElementById("editableDiv");
       var caretOffset = 0;
       if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
            var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
            preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
            preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
            caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
        } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type != "Control") {
            var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
            var preCaretTextRange = document.body.createTextRange();
            preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
            preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
            caretOffset = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
        }
        return caretOffset;
    }
```

Assume, user has selected `twitter` from the suggestion, and now I must replace `tw` with the word `twitter`
To replace the string I am following below steps,
1) Divide the string into two parts, **the** @ and tw.
2) Remove the string `tw` till the first white space or EOL from second part
3) Place the selected string (`twitter`) in between these two parts
Result must be "**the** @twitter"

**Here is the issue part**

The above technique has to be applied without losing the text format already done to the document (**the** is already bolded). So to do this, I would have to collect html content of the `editableDiv`.
Here is the collected `html` string
`<b>the</b> @tw`

As per the step 1, if I divide above string at index `5`, 2 parts would look like
part 1: `<b>the`
part 2: `</b> @tw`

step 2 would remove `</b>`
step 3 would combine two parts.
The ultimate result would look like **the @twitter**. But this is not the expected result. It is all because of the html elements present in the string.
How can I divide the html string at proper location and replace the selected option?

Comment: why you want remove </b> you can simply move everything in front of it, no?

Comment: That is where the problem is.If you go through my question one more time, I hope you'll get the point. Thanks @nzn.

Comment: what is your current index? maybe when you storing current index, you should store html(editableDiv) length instead? then you should get correct index. sorry for my english

Comment: Sorry I don't quite get the problem... why would you break the string into '<b>the' and '</b> @tw'?  Why not break at index 10  like this? '<b>the</b>' and '@tw'

Comment: as i understood he calculating characters and if you using text editor to bold text, he did not know that.

Comment: Current index is the index of '@'. I'll call a function `getCaretPosition` when user types. This way I come to the knwo the index of @. I edited my question for more clarity @nzn. Hope this will clear your doubt, If not please feel free to comment. I'll refine it.

Comment: I break it to insert selected text 'twitter' in between these two part. For latter doubt, since, I call 'getCaretPosition' when user type '@', this would give position 5 with respect to the plane text typed in div. But string manipulation has been done with html text (to preserve text format done already). So when I look for index 5, this will eventually be before "white space". Thus, it breaks there.  Thanks @martin